Using Speech Synthesis and Web Audio API to visualize text-to-speech
I am trying to create an audio visualizer that takes the text-to-speech and visualizes as it is being spoken. I was able to use this as a baseline to start with. I have sucessfully implemented a text to speech feature in the top left corner but now I am struggling to connect the two.
This is the code that I started with:
const listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
camera.add(listener);

const audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader();
audioLoader.load('./assets/Beats.mp3', function(buffer) {
    sound.setBuffer(buffer);
    window.addEventListener('click', function() {
        sound.play();
    });
});

This is what I have for text-to-speech.
const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext)();
const analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
analyser.fftSize = 32;
const dataArray = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

const gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
gainNode.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);

// Text to Speech setup
const tts = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
tts.lang = 'en-US';
const synth = window.speechSynthesis;

function speak(text) {
    tts.text = text;
    tts.volume = 100;
    synth.cancel();
    synth.speak(tts);

    const ttsStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
    const ttsSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(ttsStream.stream);
    ttsSource.connect(gainNode);

    tts.onstart = () => {
        // Capture TTS audio to the analyser
        const source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(ttsStream.stream);
        source.connect(gainNode);
    };
}

// Update the analyser with frequency data
function updateFrequency() {
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
    let average = dataArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / dataArray.length;
    uniforms.u_frequency.value = average;
    requestAnimationFrame(updateFrequency);
}
updateFrequency();

const gui = new GUI();

// Example usage
document.getElementById('speakButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let text = document.getElementById('textInput').value;
    speak(text);
});

Have been reading on Speech Synthesis and Web Audio API but at a loss for how the nodes are connected. The mp3 is read in as one continous thing while the tts splices everything to be successfully read.

Unfortunately there is no interoperability of the Web Speech API with any of the other audio related audio APIs in the browser. It's just not possible up to now.
It might change though. The latest comment here indicates that Chrome may get the ability to do speech recognition on a MediaStreamTrack.
https://github.com/WICG/speech-api/issues/66#issuecomment-2166598149
But the issue for the other way round is stalled for about 5 years.
https://github.com/WICG/speech-api/issues/69
